# Estne hoc translatio correcta?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, song-lyrics

my name is Diego and this is my very first post. I am a big fan of Avicii. I am also a beginner in Latin and was wondering if anyone could help me out checking the translation I've put together of a song called "City Lights" by this artist.

You can find the lyrics of the original song through this link; https://genius.com/Avicii-city-lights-lyrics
And my translation goes like this...

> Lūcēs urbis, tollite mē.
> Iam est tempus, nōs numquam dēscendimus.
> Nōlī timēre, sērius sum.
> Latē et nunquam inveniēmur erimus.
>
> Bene est, quia nunquam post nostrī vidēmus
> Sī ceciderimus, avēs cantābunt.
> Bene est, cum memoriae intus.
> Pulvis media noctis
> pece is in aurum mūtāre.
>
> Amplius, nē quid est vērus quidem nesciō.
> Cēterum, quid sentīre nesciō.
> Ego sum tuus vēritās dissimulāta, tua mendācia mē dēlectant
> Quia nōn possum spīrāre, mītēscereque.
> Quid sentīre nesciō
> Ita, quid sentīre nesciō.
>
> Vidē hās lūcēs, nōs ābaetimus
> Nōn inveniēmur erimus, omnīnō nōn sonāmus.
> Nōn timēmus, sēriī summus.
> Amor nōbīs nocēre nōn potest, iam dēfendimur ab mendāciīs.

I certainly am very doubtful on almost any conjugation really haha. I apologize beforehand. I appreciate your time reading and your help. Have a great day!

Comment: Also if anyone is willing to listen to the song, you can find it on your prefered app or streaming devise. Though I would warn you to skip the first minute of the song since it doesn't contain but instrumental and I wouldn't like it to be bothersome lol. Vocals start at exactly 0:59 seconds! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Diego! Going through the whole translation can be a bit much to ask for. You might get more useful responses if you ask a more focused question, picking a single sentence, posting both the original and your version (I won't follow a link in order to understand a question better, and I know I'm not alone), and making it clear what makes you doubt your own translation. Once you get some useful feedback, you can apply that to the rest of the project and then go and ask another question.

Comment: Okay, Joonas, understood. Thank you very much! Will do.